# String encoding of win32print results

Tags: python, string, python-2.7, unicode, utf-8

I have a non-literal string that is programmatically obtained from the title of a printed document online.

When I try to commit it to MongoDB, I get:

```
bson.errors.InvalidStringData: strings in documents must be valid UTF-8: 'wxPython: Windows Styles and Events Hunter \xab The Mouse Vs. The Python'
```

String retrieval code:

```
for printStats in printers:

    handle = win32print.OpenPrinter(printStats[2])
    queued = win32print.EnumJobs(handle, 0, -1, 1)

    for printJob in queued:

        username = printJob['pUserName']
        computer = printJob['pMachineName']
        document = printJob['pDocument']
        identity = printJob['JobId']
        jobstate = printJob['Status']

print document
> "wxPython: Windows Styles and Events Hunter « The Mouse Vs. The Python"
```

Comment: What type of database and what is the thrown exception?

Comment: How about storing/restoring this string in base64 encoded form?

Comment: MongoDB stores strings as UTF-8. The Python driver allows you to pass UTF-8 encoded strings or Unicodes. It sounds like your string is neither. You must understand encoding before throwing `encode` and `decode` around. The exception is if wish to exclude non-ASCII from your tables.

Comment: Please provide a reproducible problem - http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: **Please show the code that throws an exception**. Please show the output of `type (your_string)` and `your_string.encode("hex")`. If the string is an `str` then `encode("hex")` will help to identify the character encoding. Also, please confirm that your database is not limited to ASCII.

Comment: @MalikBrahimi, StackOverflow is a open forum. Questions should be answered in a generic, reproducible fashion so that others will benefit - I'm surprised I need to tell someone of your SO reputation that :\

Comment: @MalikBrahimi Me too I think that this problem can be solved without knowing the secret details of your project.  Read the [Python 2 Unicode howto](https://docs.python.org/2/howto/unicode.html) if you're not familiar with the difference between bytes and characters. Then, follow Alastair's suggestion to decode the bytes to text after calling `win32print.EnumJobs`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your comments in other answers, I can see that the error you get is:

```
bson.errors.InvalidStringData: strings in documents must be valid UTF-8: 'wxPython: Windows Styles and Events Hunter \xab The Mouse Vs. The Python'
```

As `«` is encoded as `\xab`, this means that the string is likely encoded in iso-8995-1, iso-8995-15, windows-1252/latin-1. This is likely to be related to the locale of your machine.

You simply need to decode it before passing to MongoDB, which supports Unicode strings (it is not limited to ASCII as you assert):

```
document = printJob['pDocument'].decode("latin-1")

>>> print type(document)
<type 'unicode'>
```

You can now pass `document` to the Python MongoDB driver.

To make the code portable, you can use the codec alias `mbcs` (in place of 'latin-1'). `mbcs` is automatically translated to the configured Windows locale (Thanks to @roeland)

Comment: The string is encoded - it doesn't matter where it came from. I've updated my pseudo code to match your code. I very much doubt that the encoding of `printJob['pDocument']` will change on your machine. First try my example, then consider how to make your code portable

Comment: I would guess the string will be in the local encoding of that machine, which goes by the alias `'mbcs'`.

Comment: Thanks for the tip @roeland! I didn't know that alias existed. I'll update my answer

Comment: @MalikBrahimi. Care to explain what doesn't work or do you want everyone to guess your problems?

Comment: Then your code is wrong and is still using the encoded byte string. If you are using the Unicode in the DB insert, then there's no chance the error is the same.

Comment: So shouldn't UTF-8 take care of this all?

Comment: There's a lot of legacy code around that predates multibyte character encoding, like UTF-8 or UTF-16. In the Windows world, you're more likely to use 8bit codepages or UTF-16. It's important to understand encoding and why you need to decode and encode.

Answer (score 0):

The default mode for encoding is `'strict'`, which will throw an error.

```
>>> s = u"wxPython: Windows Styles and Events Hunter « The Mouse Vs. The Python"
>>> s.encode('ascii')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\xab' in position 43: ordinal not in range(128)
```

If your database only accepts ASCII, you have no choice but to do a lossy encoding. In `'ignore'` mode all bytes that cannot be encoded are skipped:

```
 >>> s.encode('ascii', 'ignore')
'wxPython: Windows Styles and Events Hunter  The Mouse Vs. The Python'
```

In `'replace'` mode they are replaced by ? characters:

```
 >>> s.encode('ascii', 'replace')
'wxPython: Windows Styles and Events Hunter ? The Mouse Vs. The Python'
```

Lastly, there's `'xmlcharrefreplace'`:

```
>>> s.encode('ascii', 'xmlcharrefreplace')
'wxPython: Windows Styles and Events Hunter &#171; The Mouse Vs. The Python'
```

Comment: @MalikBrahimi not in ASCII

Comment: Because ASCII cannot encode bytes not in range(128).

Comment: @MalikBrahimi maybe watch this: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Mx70n1dL534 they are talking about your exact issue at minute 25.